# Cannot add author field in django

Tags: python, django, database

but when i'm making python manage.py makemigrations, it says that nothing has changed
and in admin panel i only have title and body fields, but not author, can you please tell me where i did some mistakes?

i have that django code in blog/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Blog Models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_details", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Comment: remove the trailing comma...

Comment: Remove the trailing comma after on_delete=models.CASCADE in the author field definition.

Comment: :| was it so simple, what a shame, thank's guys